# detect touched item changed without lifting up finger (swipe)

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created two buttons in a gridview.

I wish to achieve the following aim but no idea which method should be used?

First i touch on the 1st button, toast 1 msg will be shown. By swiping my finger over to the 2nd button without lifting up my finger, toast 2 msg will be shown.

When i lift up my finger from the screen, toast 3 msg will be shown.

Comment: That's a very odd requirement. Could you explain the purpose? Are you trying to simulate a slider style toggle button?

Comment: this app is for elderly use. by right, when i released my finger from the screen, an audio feedback of the touched app's name would be heard. if the touched app is not what they wanted, they just have to drag their finger to other apps to hear the app name. if it is the correct app, they just release their finger to open the app.

Comment: i am wondering which api method should i use to detect the "dragging" feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe can help u

```
gridview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            gridview.requestFocusFromTouch();
            gridview.setSelection(gridview.pointToPosition((int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY()));
            return true;
        }
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            gridview.clearFocus();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```